# SQL Server : remove some data from column

Tags: sql-server

I have table with a `description` column. There is some html in that column.

That html then passes to page, and render it. But sometimes there are comments met, and sometimes they are not closed. I need to clean this data.

I've found them through

```
select * from table where description like '%<!--%'`
```

I think its not correct, but I have no idea how to do it better.

Can you suggest a solution to my problem?

**Edit**
Here is some example.

```
<div class="text"> some data </div>
<ul><!-- Some comment -->
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li> <!-- Some comment
</ul>
```

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: If your code works, why do you want to change it?

Comment: You'd rather do that job with your program rather than with SQL Server. Otherwise you could always write a CLR method.

Comment: You're question is "how to clean" not "how to find", right?

Comment: The problem is that, I've got about 16000 rows, in that table, so CLR methor may be very expensive in resources solution. 
To @Andrey Gordeev, promlem is that when comment tag is openet, on my page all that is going after that tag is not rendering.

Comment: @Serge, my question is how to find and clean.

Comment: @StNickolas: You should show at least one sample description and the desired result after the update.

Comment: Is this a one-time only cleanup, or do you need to do it on every page request? Have you done anything to prevent this malformed data from entering the database in the future?

Comment: Yes, this is one-time, now it prevented from inserting comments from CLR.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [description] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp ([description])
VALUES ('
<div class="text"> some data <!--test</div>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li> <!-- Some comment
</ul>')

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT t.id, t.token
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              t.id
            , token = 
                SUBSTRING(
                      t.[description]
                    , number
                    , ABS(CHARINDEX('<', t.[description], number + 1) - number))
        FROM @temp t
        CROSS JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values n
        WHERE [type] = 'p'
            AND number <= LEN(t.[description]) - 1
            AND SUBSTRING(t.[description], number, 1) = '<'
    ) t
    WHERE t.token NOT LIKE '<!--%'
)
UPDATE t
SET [description] = (
    SELECT c.token
    FROM cte c
    WHERE c.id = t.id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @temp t

SELECT *
FROM @temp
```

**Results:**

```
<div class="text"> some data </div>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: Well, thank you it works fine, but it removes only comment to nearest '<' but I think it can be dangerous to leave tags that were commented?
For example if I had `ul` with 5 `li` but 5th was commented, and comment tag was accidently forgotten or else, it will show unpleasent 5th `li` item.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE WHEN` to check for the existence of an open comment sequence and for the non-existence of a close comment sequence and return a column that adds a closing comment if necessary.

```
SELECT * ,
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<!--', description) > 0
    AND CHARINDEX('-->', description) = 0 
  THEN description + '-->'
  ELSE description
  END AS clean_description
FROM dbo.[table]
```

Alternatively, if you want to remove the broken comment, use

```
SUBSTRING(description, 0, CHARINDEX('<!--', description))
```

for the `THEN` branch of the statement.

Comment: Good solution, Ill think of it.